# Android - how to display data from JSON file in recyclerView using filter?

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-filter

I'm relatively new to android programming here and am still at the stage of watching tutorials and referencing to materials all over the internet, so pardon me if I sounded noobish.. 
I've created a menu with sort/filter for my company app to display staff data in a recyclerView with gridLayoutManager. 
Data sorting using Collections.sort(...) works well, but when I tried filter with checkbox, my displayed gridView gets messed up again.
Below screenshot is my filter/sort menu located in the appBar.
I've also attached my entire code here.

My filter menu:

[image]

Trying to achieve: Sort in ascending/descending order name of staffs in admin department.

```
 public class MainPageFragment extends Fragment implements SortListener {

    private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private AlertDialog.Builder filterDialog;
    private ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final String infoUrl = "http://xxxxxxx.com/";
    private static final String imageUrl = "http://xxxxxxx.com/";

    private boolean sortTag;
    public static boolean nameCheck, ageCheck, idCheck;
    private TextView sortButton;
    private CheckBox adminChk, logisChk, salesChk;
    private RadioButton nameButton, ageButton, idButton;
    private EmployeeSorter sorter = new EmployeeSorter();
    int employeeAge = 0; int employeeId = 0;
    String employeeName, employeeDept, isAdmin, isLogistics, isSales;

    public MainPageFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_page, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_grid_recycler);
        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(null, 5));

        recyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View itemView, int position) {

                long currEmpId = recyclerViewAdapter.getItemId(position);

                EmployeeDetailsFragment fragmentSub = new EmployeeDetailsFragment();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putLong("empID", currEmpId);
                fragmentSub.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_page_fragment, fragmentSub);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getsInstance();
        requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
        sendJsonRequest();

        return view;
    }

    private void sendJsonRequest(){
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, infoUrl, 
                (JSONObject) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                employeeList = parseJsonResponse(response);
                recyclerViewAdapter.setEmployeeList(employeeList);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private ArrayList<Employee> parseJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {

        ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (response !=null && response.length() > 0) {

            // cast all the characters ID in the json file into jsonArray
            JSONArray idArray = response.names();

            for (int i=0; i< idArray.length(); i++){

                try {

                    long employeeId = idArray.getLong(i);
                    JSONObject currentObject = response.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(employeeId));

                    JSONObject emp_Name = currentObject.getJSONObject("name");
                    employeeName = emp_Name.getString("value");

                    JSONObject emp_age = currentObject.getJSONObject("age");
                    employeeAge = emp_age.getInt("value");

                    String thumbUrl = null;
                    if (currentObject.has("photo")){ thumbUrl = currentObject.getString("photo"); }

                    employeeDept = currentObject.getString("dept");

                    if (employeeDept.equals(isAdmin) || employeeDept.equals(isLogistics) || 
                            employeeDept.equals(isSales) || employeeDept.equals("")){

                        Employee employee = new Employee();
                        employee.setId(employeeId);
                        employee.setName(employeeName);
                        employee.setAge(employeeAge);
                        employee.setUrlThumbnail(imageUrl + thumbUrl + ".png");
                        employee.setDepartment(employeeDept);

                        employeeList.add(employee);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return employeeList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {

        } else if (id == R.id.action_filter) {

            callFilterAlert();

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_frag, menu);
    }

    private void callFilterAlert() {
        View inflater = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.layout_filter, null);

        sortButton = (TextView) inflater.findViewById(R.id.filter_sort_button);
        nameButton = (RadioButton) inflater.findViewById(R.id.filter_radio_name);
        ageButton = (RadioButton) inflater.findViewById(R.id.filter_radio_age);
        idButton = (RadioButton) inflater.findViewById(R.id.filter_radio_id);
        adminChk = (CheckBox) inflater.findViewById(R.id.filter_dept_admin);
        logisChk = (CheckBox) inflater.findViewById(R.id.filter_dept_logistics);
        salesChk = (CheckBox) inflater.findViewById(R.id.filter_dept_sales);

        setSortListeners();

        filterDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        filterDialog.setView(inflater)
                .setTitle("Choose")
                .setNegativeButton("Back", null)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        if (nameButton.isChecked()){
                            sortByName();
                        } else if (ageButton.isChecked()){
                            sortByAge();
                        } else if (idButton.isChecked()){
                            sortById();
                        }

                        sendJsonRequest();

                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = filterDialog.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }

    private void setFilterCriteria(){

        if (adminChk.isChecked()){
            isAdmin = "Admin";
        } else {
            isAdmin = "";
        }

        if (logisChk.isChecked()){
            isLogistics = "Logistics";
        } else {
            isLogistics = "";
        }

        if (salesChk.isChecked()){
            isSales = "Sales";
        } else {
            isSales = "";
        }

    }

    private void setSortListeners() {

        nameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nameButton.setChecked(true);
                ageButton.setChecked(false);
                idButton.setChecked(false);

                nameCheck = true;
                ageCheck = false;
                idCheck = false;

            }
        });

        ageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nameButton.setChecked(false);
                ageButton.setChecked(true);
                idButton.setChecked(false);

                nameCheck = false;
                ageCheck = true;
                idCheck = false;

            }
        });

        idButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nameButton.setChecked(false);
                ageButton.setChecked(false);
                idButton.setChecked(true);

                nameCheck = false;
                ageCheck = false;
                idCheck = true;

            }
        });

        // setup for the ascending/descending tag in the sort menu
        sortTag = false;
        sortButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (sortButton.getText() == "Ascending") {
                    sortButton.setText("Descending");
                    sortTag = false;
                } else {
                    sortButton.setText("Ascending");
                    sortTag = true;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void sortByName() {
        sorter.sortEmpByName(employeeList);
    }

    @Override
    public void sortByAge() {
        sorter.sortEmpByAgeAscending(employeeList);
    }

    @Override
    public void sortById() {
        sorter.sortEmpByIdAscending(employeeList);
    }

}
```

In the callFilterAlert() method, I called the function sendJsonRequest() again, is that correct to begin with or requesting of jsonFile should only done once during the onCreate()?

I can't find any tutorials on how to filter data on the internet, can anyone guide me as in where I got wrong in the code or where I can get related info on this topic?

Comment: You should avoid downloading data again and again, unless your data is very very dynamic and changes over quick intervals of time.

Comment: I see.. how can I target and filter the arrayList of employees without calling jsonRequest again?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo) comes with animations :)